# "Could not interpret activation function identifier: 256" error in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to run the following code but I got an error. Did I miss something in the codes?

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.activations import relu, elu, linear, sigmoid

def build_fc_model(layers):
    fc_model = Sequential()
    for i in range(len(layers)-1):
        fc_model.add( Dense(layers[i],layers[i+1]) )#, W_regularizer=l2(0.1)) )
        fc_model.add( Dropout(0.5) )
        if i < (len(layers) - 2):
            fc_model.add( Activation('relu') )
    fc_model.summary()
    return fc_model
fc_model_1 = build_fc_model([2, 256, 512, 1024, 1])
```

and here is the error message:

```
TypeError: Could not interpret activation function identifier: 256
```

Comment: look at the first layer you are trying to add `Dense(2,256)` , you want to add input layer not Dense as a first layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that, *you have defined an activation function that is not interpretable*. In your definition of a dense layer you have passed two argument as `layers[i]` and `layers[i+1]`.

Based on the docs [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/) for the `Dense` function:
The first argument is number of units (neurons) and the second parameter is activation function. So, it considers `layers[i+1]` as an activation function that could not be recognized by the `Dense` function.

**Inference**:
You do not need to pass next layer neurons to your dense layer. So remove `layers[i+1]` argument.

Furthermore, you have to define an input layer for your model and pass the input shape to it for your model.

Therefore, modified code should be like this:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.activations import relu, elu, linear, sigmoid
from keras.layers import InputLayer  #import input layer 

def build_fc_model(layers):
    fc_model = Sequential()
    fc_model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(784,))) #add input layer and specify it's shape
    for i in range(len(layers)-1):
        fc_model.add( Dense(layers[i]) ) #remove unnecessary second argument 
        if i < (len(layers) - 2):
            fc_model.add( Activation('relu') )
        fc_model.add( Dropout(0.5) )
    fc_model.summary()
    return fc_model
fc_model_1 = build_fc_model([2, 256, 512, 1024, 1])
```